My prvate key stolen. Potential Disperse.app \ GlobalETH hackathon exploit
My wallet private key was stolen last week. 55,000 USDT and some ETH gas lost.
Not TRX or BNB taken. Funds got sold on KuCoin and HTX in 6 transactions.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x528f31145f32156b52ea4b3bcede3c41426700c05844eb25e3c86f5fcd6eb695
I reported to police, and do investigation how hacker got access to the key.
Please, help me to identify explot.
Full background - I used Trustwallet (quite old ver 6.12(6129) on Iphone and new 8.24.3 version on Android), Tronlink (new v.4.14.1 on IpHone  + chrome extension) and Metamask (Iphone v7.31.0(1432) + chrome extension)
I have not signed any contracts with this wallet for last year, except for those related to GlobalETH hackton participation, also made giveeth donation once.
Disperse.app is hackathon distribution app used by organizer, for no reason it was sending me MNT that is scam token:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xccc00d6d983fac59608aad4d3bf0dafa0d02bdc81eef50090e9496163f6ce9f0
that I never swap although
Can Disperse.app contract be the reason for the exploit? malicious contract?

Track your history to see where you gave allowance to withdraw those tokens.
